# delete time based indices on elastic search older than 30 days using date math expression in JAVA gives indexNotExists exception

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-java-api, date-math, elasticsearch-indices

want to delete time based indices on elastic search older than some specific (let's say 30) days using date math expression in JAVA.

> Trying to implement following approach in our spring boot application using Transaport Client but getting index not exist exception.
>   https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date-math-index-names.html

When the same URI encoded index name (which is passed to DELETE INDEX API) is used to search index using query GET uri_encoded_index_name on kibana, It shows that index exists.

Is there something I am missing out ?
Is there any better approach to do that without using curator and wilcard characters?

code snippet:

```
String indexName = "<" + indexNameStaticPart + "{now/d-30d{MMddYYYY}}>";     
String encodedIndexName = UriEncoder.encode( indexName ).replace( "/", "%2F" );      
AcknowledgedResponse response = client.admin().indices().delete( new DeleteIndexRequest( encodedIndexName ) ).actionGet();
```

encodedIndexName : %3Cstring__string_string__%7Bnow%2Fd-30d%7BMMddyyyy%7D%7D%3E

kibana:

```
GET encodedIndexName 
DELETE encodedIndexName
```

Comment: It probably would help to see some code that leads to your error message :)

Comment: String indexName = "<" + indexNameStaticPart + "{now/d-30d{MMddYYYY}}>";
encodedIndexName = UriEncoder.encode( indexName ).replace( "/", "%2F" );
AcknowledgedResponse response = client.admin().indices().delete( new DeleteIndexRequest( encodedIndexName ) ).actionGet();

Comment: You might be interested in reading about Curator: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/about-features.html
It is a tool that you can install that will automatically delete old indices for  you, among other features

Comment: Yeah but I am curious to know why this is not working out

Comment: plus we also need to schedule job to perform index deletion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it without URI encoding..

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/delete-time-based-indices-on-elastic-search-older-than-30-days-using-date-math-expression-in-java-gives-indexnotexists-exception/171365